# PHP Database based session data

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to come up with a session handler that uses a database to store the details.

One point of this is that if a sessions data is currently being used then I do not want them to be loaded yet (until the first script has finished and updated the data).

I have a basic class to do this which is seemingly working and is below with a small test script:-

```
<?php

class MySessionHandler implements SessionHandlerInterface
{

    private $db = null;

    public function open($savePath, $sessionName)
    { 
        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        $name = 'em_sessions';
        $this->db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $name);
        return true;
    }

    public function close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function read($session_key)
    {
        $this->db->autocommit(FALSE);

        if($stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM sessions WHERE session_key = ? FOR UPDATE"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $session_key);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo $stmt->error." - ".$stmt->errno."<br />";
            $retry = 0;
            while ($stmt->errno == 1213 and $retry++ < 20)
            {
                usleep(50);
                $stmt->execute();
                echo $stmt->error." - ".$stmt->errno."<br />";
            }
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->bind_result($data);
            $stmt->fetch();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Unable to prepare statement ".$this->db->error."<br />";
        }
        return $data;
    }

    public function write($session_key, $data)
    {

        $time = time();
        if($stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO sessions (set_time, data, session_key) VALUES (?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE set_time=VALUES(set_time), data=VALUES(data)"))
        {
            echo "Written(".time().")<br />";
            $stmt->bind_param('iss', $time, $data, $session_key);
            $stmt->execute();

            $this->db->commit();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Unable to prepare statement ".$this->db->error."<br />";
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function destroy($session_key)
    {
        if($stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE session_key = ?"))
        {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $session_key);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Unable to prepare statement ".$this->db->error."<br />";
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function gc($maxlifetime)
    {
        if($stmt = $this->db->prepare("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE set_time < ?"))
        {
            $old = time() - $max;
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $old);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Unable to prepare statement ".$this->db->error."<br />";
        }
        return true;
    }

}

$handler = new MySessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler($handler, true);
session_start();
echo session_id()."<br />";

echo "<a href='http://localhost/TestArea/session_test.php'>Do Me</a><br />";

if (!array_key_exists('cnt', $_SESSION))
{
    echo "No session cnt found so initialising<br />";
    $_SESSION['cnt'] = 0;
}

echo "Page called ".++$_SESSION['cnt']." times (".time().")<br />";

sleep(2);

session_write_close();

sleep(2);

echo "Ended(".time().")<br />";
```

The basic class SELECTs the session details with FOR UPDATE to lock the row (the session id is a unique key), having turning auto commit off. When the session details are to be saved (ie, end of script or when session_write_close() is called ) a method is called to do an insert of the session details with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and then do a commit to free off the lock.

The idea of the test script is that it loads the session data, waits a few seconds, calls session_write_close() (which should trigger the session details to be written to the table, and free the lock off for the next attempt to grab the table) then waits another few seconds before ending the script.

This is just to test that the session is locked while required and then freed off for the next script using the same session id.

However while testing this I have an odd issue. If I trigger half a dozen runs of this script at once (there is a link on the page - and just click that link with the middle mouse button half a dozen times) then the first one runs fine. But the 2nd is not triggered until the first script has finished (ie, the start time of the 2nd occurrence is the same as the end time of the first occurrence). This strikes me as wrong.

The 3rd occurrence onwards will start quicker. Their start time will be when the previous occurrences session details were written to the table. This is what I would expect.

My confusion is down to why I am getting a difference between the 2nd and subsequent occurrences of the script. I real use the way the subsequent ones are processed would be fine, but the first would be a potential bigger problem; it would also be the situation that would occur most often.

It might be something simple that I have missed.

Session data table is as folows:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (
  `set_time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `session_key` char(32) NOT NULL,
  `data` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_key`),
  KEY `set_time` (`set_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Interesting question, and here's a longshot attempt at figuring out what the problem *might* be - check if you're doing pipelined HTTP requests. You haven't said which browser you used or which server is in question, and *maybe* they're pipelining HTTP requests, which would shift the blame on the totally different part than the one you're suspecting (that part being browser <> webserver communication rather than your script). If you could check that one out and rule it out (unless it is the culprit), that would help towards further debugging.

Comment: @N.B. - Cheers for the idea. It does not seem to be browser related and behaves the same was in Opera, Chrome and Firefox. Server wise it is behaving the same on a WAMP server on my Windows machine and also when uploaded to a Linux box. However it has triggered me to try something else. I have also saved the start time of the script (before the session start) and output that. The 2nd and subsequent runs of the script has this start time when the first has finished. Seems the whole script is blocked not just the sessions.

Comment: Yes, that's what pipelining would do. It's the default behavior of Apache sadly. One way to rule it out is to actually perform requests from two different machines (different pipes all together). I'm suggesting this because I had an issue with a file download that I coded way, way back. It was odd because I couldn't download 2 files at once (by middle clicking the link). 2nd would always start after 1st has finished. Pipelining was the culprit and not the code as I initially thought.

Comment: Thanks. This is an area I know pretty much nothing about. Why would this affect the 2nd script, but not subsequent ones? Any idea how I turn it off? Or do I need to fudge it with sending a header to close the connection (which would be impractical in general use)?

Comment: @N.B. - as an aside, just checked and while Firefox does display this issue, in my Firefox config pipelining is not enabled.

Comment: Right, the reason it happens is because the same socket on your client is used to handle multiple HTTP requests. That saves on resources (in theory) but what tends to happen is that if you fire requests 1, 2 and 3, you're going to receive them back in that order and ONLY after the processing has been finished. This is what *might* be happening with request #1 and #2 that you're experiencing - the 2nd one doesn't even start until 1st one is done. That's a symptom of pipelining. I would invoke the same script from two different machines to test whether it really is the case or not.

Comment: @N.B. - Now I am really confused. Running it from 2 machines worked, as runs were concurrent between the machines. However neither machine suffered from the extra delay between the 1st and 2nd triggers, and the darn thing is now working happily in Firefox (no extra delay) but not in Chrome.

Comment: Well, that just means your code and logic are ok. The issue lies in the socket communication between the client and the server. I don't know whether you have proxies between your web server and your client(s), but if you do that could be an issue. Any chance you can try using nginx instead of Apache?

Comment: @N.B. - Thank you for your time and effort. No proxies involved currently. Not sure whether I can try using nginx but it is a good idea.